# ui-router : Transition template never shown up

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have tried to implement SPA using ui-router.

I implemented ng-click handler function which calls `$state.transitionTo` function in `ExpertController`.
I expected the template which url is `/expert/{expertId}/profile` is shown up into `ui-view` named `expertProfile`.

Transition is well. I could see the url changed. 
( /#/experts to /#experts/{expertId} )

But the template never shown up in the `ui-view`. What is the problem ?

```js
/*  app.route.js */
 
 .state('experts', {
  url : '/experts',
  templateUrl : "expert/view",
  controller : "ExpertController"
 }).state('experts.profile', {
  url : '/{expertId}'
  , views : {
   'expertProfile' :  function($stateParams){
    return "expert/" + $stateParam.expertId + "/profile";
   }
  }
 })
    

/* app.js */
    
     app.controller('ExpertController', function($scope, $http, $sce, $state) {
  $scope.$ctrl = this;
  
  $scope.tab = 'total';
  
  $scope.setTab = function (tabid){
   $scope.tab = tabid;
  } 
  $scope.isSelected = function (tabid) {
   return $scope.tab === tabid;
  }
  
  $scope.expertTalkList = "";
  
  this.viewExpertProfile = function (expert){
   $state.transitionTo('experts.profile', {expertId : expert});
  }
 
});
```

```html
<!-- #/experts-->
<div class="sub_content">
 <ul class="nav clearfix" id="expertTabs">
  <li class="nav_active" tab-id="total" ng-class="{nav_active:isSelected('total')}" ng-click="setTab('total')">전체</li>
  <li tab-id="live" ng-class="{nav_active:isSelected('live')}" ng-click="setTab('live')">방송</li>
  <li tab-id="join" ng-class="{nav_active:isSelected('join')}" ng-click="setTab('join')">가입</li>
 </ul>
 <div class="scroll" id="expertTalkList">
  <ul class="user_list expert_list list" ng-include="'expert/list'" ng-show="isSelected('total')">
  </ul>
  <ul class="user_list expert_list list" ng-include="'expert/list?sectionId=live'" ng-show="isSelected('live')">
  </ul>
  <ul class="user_list expert_list list" ng-include="'expert/list?sectionId=join'" ng-show="isSelected('join')">
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="profile_wrap" id="profile-wrap" ui-view="expertProfile">

</div>


<!-- /experts/list -->

<c:forEach items="${result.list }" var="expert">
    <!-- When clicked here, webpage transitons to #/experts/{expertId} but the template /expert/{expertId}/profile never shown up in ui-view -->
    <li class="clearfix" expert-id="${expert.userId }" ng-click="$ctrl.viewExpertProfile(${expert.userId })"> 
     <div class="circle_thumb "><img src="${expert.thumbUrl }" alt="expert_thumbs"  onerror="this.src='img/thumb_default_01.png'"></div>
          <div class="cont">
              <div class="tit">${expert.title }</div>
              <div class="sub_tit">${expert.content}</div>
              <div class="update clearfix">
                  <span>업데이트:</span>
                 <!--  <span class="update_icons"><img src="img/icon_recommend.png" alt=""></span>
                  <span class="update_icons"><img src="img/icon_strategy.png" alt=""></span>
                  <span class="update_icons"><img src="img/icon_ars.png" alt=""></span> -->
                  <c:forEach items="${expert.recentlyUpdated}" var="updatedItem">
                   <span class="update_icons"><img src="img/icon_${updatedItem }.png" alt=""></span>
                  </c:forEach>
              </div>
          </div>
    </li>
</c:forEach>


<!-- /expert/{expertId}/profile -->
    <div class="profile_area">
     <div class="wrap_size">
        <div class="profile_img">
          ...
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found problem.

```
.state('experts.profile', {
        url : '/{expertId}'
        , views : {
            'expertProfile' :  function($stateParams){
                return "expert/" + $stateParam.expertId + "/profile";
            }
        }
```

This code was wrong.

`views.expertProfile` shuld be a JSON object and s was missing in `$stateParams`. 
I changed this code as

```
'expertProfile' : {
 templateUrl : function($stateParams){
                return "expert/" + $stateParams.expertId + "/profile";
            }
}
```